# Use a string containing qutation marks to specify a filepath for ofstream in C++

Tags: c++, string, ofstream

I'm trying to pass a string as a path for an ofstream. 
I'm using the .c_str() function but the programm runns through without generating the file.

```
ifstream path_stream ("config.txt");
path_stream >> path;
path_stream.close();
ofstream datum (path.c_str());
```

The contents of `config.txt` is

```
"test.txt"
```

If I give that directly to `ofstream`, the program creates the file `test.txt`.
With the string it just runs the program without any output.

Comment: Your code looks just fine, though _"Doesn't work"_ is a way too vague description of the errors you get. Provide a [MCVE] please, that reproduces your problem. What's the content of `config.txt` actually?

Comment: config.txt has just  "test.txt"  in it (with quotation marks). If I give that directly to ofstream, the program creates the file test.txt.
With the string it just runns the programm without any output.

Comment: Files can't have names with ". You're trying to create one.

Comment: Remove quotation marks from `config.txt` and it will work as expected.

Comment: @DerOmmel So `"test.txt"` in quotation marks tries to open a file using the  filename with these quotation marks literally. I doubt your file is actually named `"test.txt"` (including those quotation marks). Also after removing the quotation marks, ensure that the file exists in the current working directory where your program runs. And last but not least check the result of  `ofstream datum (path.c_str());` using `datum.fail()`.

Comment: ok it woks without the ""
thank you

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I edited my question. Mayby it's helpful...

Comment: @DerOmmel Well, I banged it in shape a bit (though a [MCVE] is still missing), and wrote an answer.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'm learning :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have put the filepath in your `config.txt` file in quotation marks.

> If I give that directly to `ofstream`, the program creates the file `test.txt`.

I suppose you've tried

```
ofstream datum ("test.txt");
```

which is very different from

```
ofstream datum ("\"test.txt\"");
              // ^^        ^^
```

as that's the equivalent of

```
ofstream datum (path.c_str());
```

after `path` was read from the file.

So just remove the quotation marks from your `config.txt` file.